# Flutter : No permissions found in manifest for: []33, No permissions found in manifest for: []22

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to display the list of files in my Flutter app. On emulated Android 13 device everything works fine, but when I use my phone (Android 10) I get an error:

```
No permissions found in manifest for: []33, No permissions found in manifest for: []22
```

Here is my code:

```dart
void getPermissions() async {
  List<Permission> permissions = [
    Permission.storage,
    Permission.manageExternalStorage,
    Permission.audio,
  ];

  for (var permission in permissions) {
    var status = await permission.status;
    if (status.isDenied) {
      await permission.request();
    }
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```

And manifest file:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:label="music_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried using `flutter clean` command and downgrading the version of [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package.

Comment: you can uninstall the app and run again app,